# Unable to nest custom Jersey providers

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

Jersey throws an exception when I try to reference one custom provider from another.

This test case

```
public class NestedProvidersTest extends JerseyTest {
    public NestedProvidersTest() throws TestContainerException {
        super(new LowLevelAppDescriptor.Builder(new DefaultResourceConfig(Resource.class, ParentProvider.class, ChildProvider.class)).build());
    }

    @Test public void test() {
        resource().path("/").get(String.class);
    }

    @Path("/") public static class Resource {
        @Context private Parent parent;

        @GET public String get() {
            return "hello";
        }
    }

    public interface Parent {}
    public interface Child {}

    @Provider public static class ParentProvider extends PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider<Context, Parent> {
        @Context private Child child;

        public ParentProvider() {
            super(Parent.class);
        }

        @Override public Injectable<Parent> getInjectable(ComponentContext ic, Context context) {
            return new Injectable<Parent>() {
                @Override public Parent getValue() {
                    return new Parent(){};
                }
            };
        }
    }

    @Provider public static class ChildProvider extends PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider<Context, Child> {
        public ChildProvider() {
            super(Child.class);
        }

        @Override public Injectable<Child> getInjectable(ComponentContext ic, Context context) {
            return new Injectable<Child>() {
                @Override public Child getValue() {
                    return new Child(){};
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

gives me the exception

```
Apr 05, 2013 7:02:41 PM com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.grizzly2.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer <init>
INFO: Creating low level grizzly2 container configured at the base URI http://localhost:9998/
Apr 05, 2013 7:02:41 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17.1 02/28/2013 12:47 PM'
Apr 05, 2013 7:02:43 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private NestedProvidersTest$Child NestedProvidersTest$ParentProvider.child

com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.TestContainerException: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.grizzly2.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer.<init>(GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.java:106)
    at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.grizzly2.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.create(GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.java:77)
    at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.getContainer(JerseyTest.java:345)
    at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.<init>(JerseyTest.java:220)
    at NestedProvidersTest.<init>(NestedProvidersTest.java:22)
[snip]
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:172)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.grizzly2.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer.<init>(GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.java:102)
    ... 29 more
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this behaviour not supported by Jersey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More appropriate question should be:
`is this behavior not supported by Jersey 1.17?`

I don't want to play guessing game, so I can only tell you that it can be done with Jersey 2.

Why it does not work in 1.17? Maybe because that `Child` dependency is not available during registration of providers.

Jersey 2 uses JSR-330 that is @Inject and all that and the way to do something you want to do is to use [javax.inject.Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Provider.html).

Then you would use some kind of binder to register injectables but skipping all the details when you use Provider you don't expect T to be injected during registration. It will be retrieved later during `Provider#get`

Example from request scoped filter:

```
@Inject
private Provider<ResourceInfo> resourceInfo;
```

If I would like to do just these:

```
@Inject
ResourceInfo resourceInfo
```

then it would fail just like it failed for you.

If you can upgrade to 2 then I think it's worth it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said I tested this in Jersey 1.17.1